# Delete cells without shifting them up

Tags: excel, delete-row, shift, vba

I have vba macro to delete a selection of cells. Its shifting the cells up automatically after deleting them. I don't want the cells to be shifted up, as I have a chart below the cells and everything gets disturbed if they are shifted.

Here is the code I am using to delete cells

```
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select
ActiveSheet.Range("C2:H8").Select
Selection.Delete
```

Let me know how can I delete them without shifting up.

Comment: When the cells are deleted, the cells from below or from left move to take their place. Regarding your charts, how do they get disturbed?

Answer (score 5):

You could  use

```
ActiveSheet.Range("C2:H8").ClearContents
```

that'll empty the content without shifting anything.

Comment: @Dick: I tried clearcontents, But getting an error "Cannot change Merged cells" as I do have few merged cells.

Comment: Ooh, I don't like merged cells.  Try `ActiveSheet.Range("C1:H8").MergeArea.ClearContents`

Comment: I've just tried on a mix selection of ordinary and merged cells, and it works perfectly fine. What version of Excel are you using ?

Answer (score 3):

If i understand correctly, I think using ClearContents instead of Delete should provide the functionality you are looking for.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa223828%28v=office.11%29.aspx

Alternatively, you can specify how you want the cells to shift, if that is better suited to what you are trying to do:

From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa223863%28v=office.11%29.aspx

> expression.Delete(Shift)
>
> expression Required. An expression that returns a Range object.
>
> Shift   Optional Variant. Used only with Range objects. Specifies how to shift cells to replace deleted cells. Can be one of the following XlDeleteShiftDirection constants: xlShiftToLeft or xlShiftUp. If this argument is omitted, Microsoft Excel decides based on the shape of the range.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered just ClearContents?

```
ActiveSheet.Range("C2:H8").ClearContents
```

If you have problems with merged cells try:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("C2:H8").Value = ""
```

Comment: I tried clearcontents, But getting an error "Cannot change Merged cells" as I do have few merged cells.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was easy to use Delete without disturbing row sequence simply starting the loop from the very bottom line towards the header of the selected scope:

```
Cells(rw, 4).Activate
For i = rw To 1 Step -1
   Set Clr = Cells(i, 4)
   If Not Clr.Text Like "R*" Then
    Clr.EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp

   End If
Next i
```